# How to convert xml string format to php array

Tags: php, xml, arrays

Hello i have php var (string) look like xml:
its not real xml file just php string with same structure like xml.
and i need to get the ROW_DATA fields from it in php loop.
(this xml structure i get from soap web service).

7/9/2013
        10:01:29
        AM
    7/9/2013
        10:01:29
        AM

```
<ROW_DATA>
    <AMOUNT_ROOMS>2</AMOUNT_ROOMS>
    <SUPP_MOVIE_NAME>tiz</SUPP_MOVIE_NAME>
    <AMOUNT_NIS>3680</AMOUNT_NIS>
    <PRICE_DOCKET_ID>1233</PRICE_DOCKET_ID>
</ROW_DATA>

<ROW_DATA>
    <AMOUNT_ROOMS>1</AMOUNT_ROOMS>
    <SUPP_MOVIE_NAME>mantiz</SUPP_MOVIE_NAME>
    <AMOUNT_NIS>3690</AMOUNT_NIS>
    <PRICE_DOCKET_ID>1234</PRICE_DOCKET_ID>
</ROW_DATA>

<StartTime>7/9/2013
    10:01:29
    AM</StartTime>
<EndTime>7/9/2013
    10:01:30
    AM</EndTime>
```

now i need to get this in php array...
any ideas please???

Comment: Check out [simplexml](http://us1.php.net/simplexml)

Comment: what structure of array do you need?

Comment: i just need all the ROW_DATA info Something like:
`
$room1_AMOUNT = $rooms[0]['AMOUNT_ROOMS'];
$room2_AMOUNT = $rooms[1]['AMOUNT_ROOMS'];
`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

imo, better way is to:

1. use heredoc with xml definition

   ```
   $string = <<<XML
   <?xml version='1.0'?>
   ... // your xml here
   XML;
   ```
2. return array, not `SimpleXMLElement Object` if he needs it, with

   `$xml = (array)simplexml_load_string($string);`

Comment: Hello vladkras Thanks for the reply .
this syntax is ok?

Comment: @pey22 hi, yes, `(array)` is official php [convertion](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) (scroll down to _Converting to array_ section), also `<?xml version='1.0'?>` is not neccessary for simplexml, but I think it's a good coding style

Answer (score 2):

```
$str = '<ROOT>
    <StartTime>7/9/2013
        10:01:29
        AM</StartTime>
    <EndTime>7/9/2013
        10:01:29
        AM</EndTime>

    <ROW_DATA>
        <AMOUNT_ROOMS>2</AMOUNT_ROOMS>
        <SUPP_MOVIE_NAME>tiz</SUPP_MOVIE_NAME>
        <AMOUNT_NIS>3680</AMOUNT_NIS>
        <PRICE_DOCKET_ID>1233</PRICE_DOCKET_ID>
    </ROW_DATA>

    <ROW_DATA>
        <AMOUNT_ROOMS>1</AMOUNT_ROOMS>
        <SUPP_MOVIE_NAME>mantiz</SUPP_MOVIE_NAME>
        <AMOUNT_NIS>3690</AMOUNT_NIS>
        <PRICE_DOCKET_ID>1234</PRICE_DOCKET_ID>
    </ROW_DATA>

    <StartTime>7/9/2013
        10:01:29
        AM</StartTime>
    <EndTime>7/9/2013
        10:01:30
        AM</EndTime>

</ROOT>';

$xml = simplexml_load_string($str);
print_r($xml);
```

Output:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [StartTime] => Array
        (
            [0] => 7/9/2013
        10:01:29
        AM
            [1] => 7/9/2013
        10:01:29
        AM
        )

    [EndTime] => Array
        (
            [0] => 7/9/2013
        10:01:29
        AM
            [1] => 7/9/2013
        10:01:30
        AM
        )

    [ROW_DATA] => Array
        (
            [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [AMOUNT_ROOMS] => 2
                    [SUPP_MOVIE_NAME] => tiz
                    [AMOUNT_NIS] => 3680
                    [PRICE_DOCKET_ID] => 1233
                )

            [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [AMOUNT_ROOMS] => 1
                    [SUPP_MOVIE_NAME] => mantiz
                    [AMOUNT_NIS] => 3690
                    [PRICE_DOCKET_ID] => 1234
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: WOW Thanks for the quick reply.
now how can i display them to the browser in loop not in print_r?

Comment: @pey22 throw it in a foreach and iterate over it... You can echo to your page inside the loop or assign variables to be used later.

Answer (score 0):

In addion to answer of brbcoding can append:

```
print_r($xml->xpath('/ROOT'));
```

This will return data as array.

To display them to the browser in loop you can get parts of xml
with method **xpath**
or with properties like $xml->StartTime